# Read a file from a resource and write it to disk in C#

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I have some files, which are embedded in a resource. How can I save these files on disk via C#?

Comment: What kind of files? Embedded how? What resource compiler was used to embed them?

Comment: an resx file, which consists of some binary files (excel files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using streams: GetManifestResourceStream gives you a stream to the file in the resource and using a StreamWriter you can write the contents of that stream to disk.

Answer (score 6):

This should do your job:

```
        string strTempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllBytes(strTempFile, Properties.Resources.YourBinaryFileInResource);
```

Be sure, that the FileType of the included files is set to "binary".

Answer (score 2):

You can get the resource stream, then read from the stream while writing to the file.

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("filename"))
        {
            using (Stream resourceStream = typeof(Class1).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("name of resource"))
            {
                int bytes = -1;
                while ((bytes = resourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                }
            }
        }
```

Code is completely untested, just to give you an idea.